# Differences and cohabitation between Spring and javax.transaction @Transactional annotation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jta

I'm currently dealing with a codebase where the business code uses the `@Transactional` annotation from the `javax.transaction` package. However, this software also uses spring-data JPA repositories, which uses the Spring `@Transactional` annotation. Since we discovered this, we switched to using Spring `@Transactional` annotation on all newer business code.

My questions are:

- Does using both different annotation cause any kind of problem ? I'm
  guessing not because we discovered the problem during a code
  refactoring but we didn't notice any defect related to this problem. However, I prefer to be sure
- What's the difference in behavior between the two annotations ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Depending on the Spring version in use the `java.transaction.Transactional` is ignored, support was added in Spring 4. There shouldn't be any difference in behavior between the 2.

Comment: Related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26387399/javax-transaction-transactional-vs-org-springframework-transaction-annotation-tr and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10505160/difference-between-jta-and-spring-transactional-annotations