# The attribute readOnly is undefined for the annotation type Transactional

Tags: java, spring, transactions

I am getting this error when I am putting this piece of code on a service method

```
 @Transactional(readOnly =true)
```

I am writing this code to make a transaction read only. Can you please tell me What I did wrong in this case

Comment: Can you tell us which package you have imported for `@Transactional`.

Comment: @NamanGala I was importing `javax.trasaction.Transactional`, now I got that I have to use one that was provided by spring only.

Answer (score 29):

Make sure you import `@Transactional` from `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional` and not from `javax.transaction.Transactional` as `readOnly` attribute is specific to Spring transaction.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I got that, can you please also tell me if there is any significant difference between these two apart from that ,one is provided by JavaEE and other by Spring.

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10505160/difference-between-jta-and-spring-transactional-annotations

Answer (score 3):

Add

import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;